# Continuing the enumerate numbering from other the enumerate list in the document

Tags: lists, enumerate

I have an enumerate list in my latex document as below:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item 1
\item 2
\end{enumerate}
```

I want pick the numbering of that particular list somewhere else in the document, i.e., somewhere else the enumerate list should continue from number 3. Is there anyway to do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This can be easily done with `enumitem` and the `resume` option. However, this will only work if the two `enumerate` environments follow each other (maybe separated by some text).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item First item.
\item Second item.
\end{enumerate}
Text.
\begin{enumerate}[resume]
\item Third item
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If there is a different list inbetween, you can use the following approach that is based on the `series` option of the `enumitem` package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[series=myexample]
\item First item.
\item Second item.
\end{enumerate}
Text.
\begin{enumerate}
\item a different enumerate series
\end{enumerate}
Text
\begin{enumerate}[resume=myexample]
\item Third item 
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A detailed description of the `resume` and `series` options can be found in section '3.4 Numbering, stopping, and resuming' and '3.5 Series'  (page 6)  of the [`enumitem` manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem).

Comment: Nice. I am going to delete my answer since yours is an improvement, with `series` option.

Comment: @Sigur: Sorry, I haven't seen your answer before posting my own. I have included a comment on the limitation of the `resume` option into my answer.

Comment: Don't worry, good job!

Answer (score 5):

I can think of two answers.

**Option 1** (quick, doesn't adapt to changes).

In your second list, set the `enumi` counter to the number of the last item in the first list:

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \setcounter{enumi}{2}
    \item 3
\end{enumerate}
```

**Option 2** (adapts to changes).

Create a new environment with a custom counter.

```
\newcounter{mylistcounter}
\setcounter{mylistcounter}{0}
\newenvironment{mylist}{
    \begin{enumerate}
        \setcounter{enumi}{\value{mylistcounter}}%
}{
        \setcounter{mylistcounter}{\value{enumi}}%
    \end{enumerate}
}
```

Then use the `mylist` environment instead of `enumerate` for these lists.

Answer (score 3):

- If there is no other enumerate list between  the two lists, simply load `enumitem` and use the `resume` key, like this:

  ```
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item 1
  \item 2
  \end{enumerate}

  Some text

  \begin{enumerate}[resume]
  \item 3
  \item 4
  \end{enumerate}
  ```

The `resume*` key makes the second list use, not only the same counter as the first, but also the same formatting.

- If there are other enumerate environments between the two lists, you can use the `series` key, in this vein:

  ```
  \begin{enumerate}[series=A]
  \item 1
  \item 2
  \end{enumerate}

  Some text
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*]
  \item a
  \item b
  \end{enumerate}    

  \begin{enumerate}[resume*=A]
  \item 3
  \item 4
  \end{enumerate}
  ```